# Returning Item from promise in Custom Angular Pipe

Tags: angular, angular-pipe, moltin

I built a custom pipe to return a string:

```
transform(value: string, arg?: any): any {
  if(this.result == null){return null;}
  return this.vs.GetById(value).then((variant) => {
     this.result = variant[arg];
  }).finally(() => {
  return this.result;
 })
}
```

I call it like this:

```
{{ variant.id | getProductVariant: (name$ | async) }}
```

The service that the pipe calls looks like:

```
GetById(id) {
        let promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            this.http.get(this.base_url+'v2/variations/'+id, this.options).toPromise().then(res => {
                var results = res['data'];
                resolve(results);
            }, msg => {
                reject(msg);
            });
        });
        return promise;
    }
```

However, It only returns `[object Promise]` instead of `name` in this example. What am I missing?

Comment: finally also returns a promise. try another async pipe in html

Comment: Provide a stackblit where I/we can reproduce an issue